# Map showing monthly or weekly average low temperatures in Turkey and Iran

Tags: climate, temperature, mapping, seasons

I am hoping to walk from Trabzon to Astara during October and November. I am hoping to take the route that will have the highest "average low" temperature across this period, to make camping more comfortable.

I have all the temperature charts for the cities in the region from Wikipedia. However it would be better to have maps showing similar data (for each month, or even better each week), as Wikipedia's city charts don't do enough to reveal strips of warm climates in rural areas eg along Lake Van or along Lake Urmia, or along the Aras river valley.

Is there any online map of average low temperatures for each month or week of the year which I can use?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to are *climate maps*, which show average weather values over a 30 year period. Weather forecasters will often then look at '[anomaly](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/monitoring/dyk/anomalies-vs-temperature)' maps which show how current conditions vary compared with the 30-year average.

Both these terms will help you find what you are looking for.

A quick search found [climatemaps.romgens.com/](https://climatemaps.romgens.com/), but there will be others which show the same information, perhaps in a more useful format. The website I've linked to defaults to precipitation and you have to change the variable to '*Min. temperature*' and then choose the month you are interested in.

I also found a Turkey-specific map on Word Bank Group's [Climate Knowledge Portal](https://climateknowledgeportal.worldbank.org/country/turkiye/climate-data-historical). Again, you will need to change the variable to '*average minimum surface air temperature*' and choose the months you are interested in.

Bear in mind that the thirty-year averages are for distinct periods defined by the World Meteorology Organisation. The latest one is 1991-2020, but the past few years have on average been warmer than that period. Any results you find are likely to be showing slightly cooler conditions than you will get on average these days, but climate is different to weather and the weather could be significantly warmer or colder. All you are doing is weighing the odds in your favour.

Have a great trip.

Comment: Soapbox: It's a flying shame that the internet still doesn't offer decent weekly or daily climate maps :(

Comment: (And to quantify the "slightly" [as folks may not know], global average temp shows basically about a 0.3-0.4°C rise between 2005 and now. More of that tends to found in low temps [vs high temps ], but more of it also tends to be in the very high latitudes... so such a value is probably a pretty fair guess for the adjustment on average to the Caucuses... though again, weather often varies by 10 to even 50 times that, especially as we work towards the cool season, so it's only a rough idea.  Would love a site that gives you percentage chance of certain types of conditions climatologically)